# Access excel with macros using openpyxl

Tags: python, vba, excel, openpyxl

I have an **.xlsm** file with lots of macros and sheets, which provides some graphs when filled in. I want to open the **.xlsm** file in python and fill some values to the macros in order to get the graphs . I have tried the following code but it seems that when I open the new file a message that the file is corrupted pops-up.

I use **python 2.74** and **openpyxl** version is **2.4.8**

```
import openpyxl
from xlwt import easyxf

book = openpyxl.load_workbook('macroexcel.xlsm',keep_vba=True)  #opens excel file
sheet = book.get_sheet_by_name('SheetName') #Get the sheet name
sheet['K34'] = 'Value' #Assign value to a cell connected to the macro
book.save('newexcel.xlsm') #Save
```

Is there a way to get access to the values in the macros, select them and extract the graphs using python.?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this - [How To: Add and Call Excel Macro from Python Using Pandas, Win32 and PyMySQL](https://redoakstrategic.com/pythonexcelmacro/).

It suggests Python to initiate a `win32com.client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')` to start Excel. Then, having access to the application layer, `xl.Application.Run("Macro1")`.

Comment: Please only use links as a supplementary resource. Links can go dead or the content on the other side can be changed to no longer answer the question. You can edit your answer to include the information that you linked to.

Comment: And as @mypetlion stated, we're now getting a 404 page not found error...

Answer (score 0):

You may use the

(first how to install OleTools, and importantly `oleVBA` more importantly)

how to install OleTools?
.# step1 `access https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/` (to get the vs_buildtools.exe)

.# step2 vs_buildtools.exe --norestart --passive --downloadThenInstall --includeRecommended --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NativeDesktop --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.VCTools --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.MSBuildTools

---

`from oletools.olevba import VBA_Parser, VBA_Project`

then just

`vba_parser = VBA_Parser(SRC)`

or whatever, took me a while to understand how to get it. You're not alone :)

you may google my name before sending me a nobel prize, (send those OleTools guys, actually for making life eazy) ;)